# Xcode .c file send message to objective-c (.m) file

Tags: objective-c, c

Lots functions of my program are in C file, and C has a head file therefore Objective-C files could use the functions in C, but some of the functions is use for fetch the information from the internet, for instance, somebody send a instant message to the user, and one of the functions in C file could get the information, but how could this function in C file send information to Objective-C file and show the message to the user.
Therefore my question is: how to let the function in C file sending message to Objective-C.
Cheers, pls help!

Comment: `void cStyleFunc() { [someObject someMessage]; }`

Comment: @H2CO3: Won't work in a file compiled as C.

Comment: @mipadi then why not rename *.c to *.m?

Comment: @H2CO3: You might also want to be able to compile it as C for some reason, in which case, you can't use any Objective-C constructs.

Comment: @mipadi If you want to have C functions that use Objective-C, then it's not possible to compile them as C. The last resort is using the `objc_msgSend()` family directly or using conditional compilation (this can be achieved by using preprocessor directives).

Comment: @H2CO3: It's possible, either via Objective-C's core C functions, or through callback mechanisms, to call Objective-C code from C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As H2CO3 suggests, the easiest solution is to rename the `.c` files to `.m` files and add the Objective-C.

Alternatively, have your Objective-C interface expose a header file with nothing but C function declarations where the implementation of said functions -- in a .m file -- provides the glue to your ObjC code.  (Note that this is exactly how much of CoreFoundation is implemented;  the C functions are merely glue on top of an underlying ObjC implementation).